# How to handle citations in Ipython Notebook?

Tags: latex, ipython, markdown, bibtex

What is the best way to take care of citations in Ipython Notebook? Ideally, I would like to have a bibtex file, and then, as in latex, have a list of shorthands in Ipython markdown cells, with the full references at the end of the notebook.

The relevant material I found is this: http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/ipython/nbconvert-examples/blob/master/citations/Tutorial.ipynb

But I couldn't follow the documentation very well. Can anyone explain it? Thanks so much!!

Comment: What part of the documentation is tripping you up?

Comment: I'm working on a tool to interactively add citations to notebooks, but it's a bit rough so far: https://github.com/takluyver/cite2c

Answer (score 18):

## Summary

This solution is largely based on Sylvain Deville's [excellent blog post](https://sylvaindeville.net/2015/07/17/writing-academic-papers-in-plain-text-with-markdown-and-jupyter-notebook/). It allows you to simply write `[@citation_key]` in markdown cells. The references will be formatted after document conversion. The only requirements are LaTeX and pandoc, which are both widely supported. While there is never a guarantee, this approach should therefore still work in many years time.

## Step-by-Step Guide

In addition to a working installation of jupyter you need:

1. **LaTeX** ([installation guide](http://sachaepskamp.com/LaTeX2015)).
2. **Pandoc** ([installation guide](http://pandoc.org/installing.html)).
3. A **citation style language**. Download a citation style, e.g., [APA](https://github.com/citation-style-language/styles/blob/master/apa.csl). Save the `.csl` file (e.g., `apa.csl`) into the same folder as your jupyter notebook (or specify the path to the `.csl` file later).
4. A **`.bib` file** with your references. I am using a [sample bib file](http://shelah.logic.at/listb.bib) `list.bib`. Save to the same folder as your jupyter notebook (or specify the path to the `.bib` file later).

Once you completed these steps, the rest is easy:

1. Use markdown syntax for references in markdown cells in your jupyter notebook. E.g., `[@Sh:1]` where the syntax works like this: **`([@citationkey_in_bib_file])`**. I much prefer this syntax over other solutions because it is so fast to type `[@something]`.
2. At the end of your ipython notebook, create a code cell with the following syntax to **automatically convert your document** (note that this is R code, use an equivalent command to `system()` for python):

   ```
    #automatic document conversion to markdown and then to word
    #first convert the ipython notebook paper.ipynb to markdown
    system("jupyter nbconvert --to markdown paper.ipynb")
    #next convert markdown to ms word
    conversion <- paste0("pandoc -s paper.md -t docx -o paper.docx",
                   " --filter pandoc-citeproc",
                   " --bibliography="listb.bib",
                   " --csl="apa.csl")
    system(conversion)
   ```

   Run this cell (or simply run all cells). Note that the 2nd system call is simply `pandoc -s paper.md -t docx -o paper.docx --filter pandoc-citeproc --bibliography=listb.bib --csl=apa.csl`. I merely used `paste0()` to be able to spread this over multiple lines and make it nicer to read.

   The output is a word document. **If you prefer another document**, check out [this guide](http://pandoc.org/demos.html) for alternative syntax.

---

#Extras

1. If you do not like that your converted document includes the syntax for the document conversion, insert a markdown cell above and below the code cell with the syntax for the conversion. In the cell above, enter `<!--` and in the cell below enter `-->`. This is a regular HTML command for a comment, so the syntax will in between these two cells will be **evaluated but not printed**.
2. You can also include a **yaml header** in your first cell. E.g.,

   ```
    ---
    title: This is a great title. 
    author: Author Name
    abstract: This is a great abstract
    ---
   ```

Comment: While converting the `.ipynb` to `.md` with `pandoc` the reference is converted to `\[@something\]`, which doesn't give the desired output when compiling to for example a pdf file. Is this explained by using `pandoc` instead of `nbconvert`?

Comment: @Flo Your code worked for me after tweaking it for Python. Among other small changes, I installed pandoc using brew, I had to replace `" --filter pandoc-citeproc"` with `" --citeproc"`. Thanks for the explanation of why there was a `copy0()` function in the code at first. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 10):

You can use the *Document Tools* of the [Calico suite](http://calicoproject.org), which can be installed separately with:

```
sudo ipython install-nbextension https://bitbucket.org/ipre/calico/downloads/calico-document-tools-1.0.zip
```

Read the [tutorial](http://jupyter.cs.brynmawr.edu/hub/dblank/public/Examples/Calico%20Document%20Tools%20and%20Bibtex.ipynb) and watch the [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=86FTd1pcoZ4) for more details.

---

Warning: only the cited references are processed. Therefore, if you fail to cite an article, it won't appear in the References section. As a little working example, copy the following in a **Markdown** cell and press the "book" icon.

```
<!--bibtex

@Article{PER-GRA:2007,
  Author    = {P\'erez, Fernando and Granger, Brian E.},
  Title     = {{IP}ython: a System for Interactive Scientific Computing},
  Journal   = {Computing in Science and Engineering},
  Volume    = {9},
  Number    = {3},
  Pages     = {21--29},
  month     = may,
  year      = 2007,
  url       = "http://ipython.org",
  ISSN      = "1521-9615",
  doi       = {10.1109/MCSE.2007.53},
  publisher = {IEEE Computer Society},
}

@article{Papa2007,
  author = {Papa, David A. and Markov, Igor L.},
  journal = {Approximation algorithms and metaheuristics},
  pages = {1--38},
  title = {{Hypergraph partitioning and clustering}},
  url = {http://www.podload.org/pubs/book/part\_survey.pdf},
  year = {2007}
}

-->

Examples of citations: [CITE](#cite-PER-GRA:2007) or [CITE](#cite-Papa2007).
```

This should result in the following added Markdown cell:

> ## References
>
> <sup>^</sup> Pérez, Fernando and Granger, Brian E.. 2007. *IPython: a System for Interactive Scientific Computing*. [URL](http://ipython.org)
>
> <sup>^</sup> Papa, David A. and Markov, Igor L.. 2007. *Hypergraph partitioning and clustering*. [URL](http://www.podload.org/pubs/book/part_survey.pdf)

Comment: This looks very useful! But unfortunately under the References session,  journals' names do not show up at all... Do you have any suggestions on this? Thanks so much!

Comment: @user3698176. Indeed. I have created an issue: https://bitbucket.org/ipre/calico/issue/218/notebook-extension-documenttools-no

Comment: The link to the Calico suite is also dead now.  Is the project dead too?

Comment: According to https://bitbucket.org/ipre/calico/issues/221/calicoprojectorg-unreachable# this project is no longer in active development.  What's more, the devs have not seen fit to update their own README with a corrected URL.  But the documentation is now here: http://wiki.roboteducation.org/Calico.

Comment: The code now lives here: https://github.com/Calysto/notebook-extensions

Answer (score 1):

I was able to run it with the following approach:

- Insert the html citation as in the [tutorial](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/ipython/nbconvert-examples/blob/master/citations/Tutorial.ipynb) you mentioned.
- Create `ipython.bib` in the "standard" `bibtex` format.  It goes into the same file as your `*.ipynb` notebook file.
- Create the template file as in the tutorial, also in the same directory or else in the (distribution dependent) directory with the other templates.  On my system, that's `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/nbconvert/templates/latex`.
- The tutorial has the template extend `latex_article.tplx`.  On my distribution, it's `article.tplx` (without `latex_`).
- Run `nbconvert` with `--to latex`; that generates an `.aux` file among other things.  Latex will complain about missing references.
- Run `bibtex yournotebook.aux`; this generates `yournotebook.bbl`.  You only need to re-run this if you change references.
- Re-run `nbconvert` either with `--to latex` or with `--to pdf`.  This generates a `.tex` file, or else runs all the way to a `.pdf`.

If you want html output, you can use [pandoc](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/171793/bibtex-to-html-markdown-etc-using-pandoc) to assemble the references into a tidy citation page.  This may require some hand-editing to make an html page you can reference from your main document.

Comment: I get an error `TemplateNotFound: article.tlpx`, when doing nbconvert

Comment: @Vass: There have been some version changes since I wrote the answer.  Which version of `IPython` (or `jupyter`) are you using?  What OS are you using?

Comment: @Vass: I'm running Ubuntu 14.04, and ipython version 4.0.0, installed with `pip`.  My `article.tplx` is in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nbconvert/templates/latex/article.tplx`.  Any chance you mis-spelled `article.tlpx` rather than `article.tplx` in the template?

Comment: On my Ubuntu Focal there is no `*.aux` file, how can I make it?
`ipython3` is of version 7.13.0 and `jupyter-nbconvert` is of version 5.6.1.

Answer (score 0):

If you know that you will be converting your notebook to latex anyway, consider simply adding a "Raw" cell (Ctrl+M R) to the end of the document, containing the bibliography just as you would put it in pure LaTeX.

For example, when I need to reference a couple of external links, I would not even care to do a proper BibTeX thing and simply have a "Raw" cell at the end of the notebook like that:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{1}
\bibitem{post1} 
Holography in Simple Terms. K.Tretyakov (blog post), 2015.\\
\url{http://fouryears.eu/2015/07/24/holography-in-simple-terms/}

\bibtem{book1}
The Importance of Citations. J. Smith. 2010.
\end{thebibliography}
```

The items can be cited in other Markdown cells using the usual `<cite data-cite="post1">(KT, 2015)</cite>`

Of course, you can also use proper BibTeX as well. Just add the corresponding Raw cell, e.g:

```
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{papers}
```

This way you do not have to bother editing a separate template file (at the price of cluttering the notebook's HTML export with raw Latex, though).

Comment: But the references don't appear in the jupyter file. So how do I get that ?

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at the latex_envs extension in https://github.com/ipython-contrib/IPython-notebook-extensions (install from this repo, it is the most recent version). This extension contains a way to integrate bibliography using bibtex files and standard latex notation, and generates a bibliography section at the end of the notebook. Style of citations can be (to some extent) customized. Some documentation here https://rawgit.com/jfbercher/latex_envs/master/doc/latex_env_doc.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Python version of Flo's answer:

```
# automatic document conversion to markdown and then to word
# first convert the ipython notebook paper.ipynb to markdown

import os

os.system("jupyter nbconvert --to markdown paper.ipynb")

# next convert markdown to MS Word
md_to_word = '''pandoc -s paper.md -t docx -o paper.docx --citeproc --bibliography="references.bib" --csl="frontiers.csl" '''

os.system(md_to_word)
```

Check that the .csl file is xml and not html.